# Local storage across domains using a Greasemonkey script

Tags: greasemonkey

Is it possible to store data across domains using a Greasemonkey script? I want to allow a Javascript object to be accessed from multiple websites that are using the same Greasemonkey script.

Comment: I think it might be possible to store data using `GM_setvalue`, but I'm not sure if it can be shared across domains.

Comment: Relevant documentation for `GM_setvalue` can be found here: http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue

Comment: It might be possible to share data between scripts somehow: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=greasemonkey+share+data+between+scripts&oq=greasemonkey+share+data&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i30.631.7873.0.8967.37.28.5.0.0.1.466.3611.20j3j2j1j2.28.0.les%3Beqn%2Ccconf%3D1-2%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Crate_low%3D0-035%2Crate_high%3D0-035%2Csecond_pass%3Dfalse%2Cnum_suggestions%3D2%2Cignore_bad_origquery%3Dtrue%2Conetoken%3Dfalse..0.0...1c.1.zI9OfljWoTg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.dmQ&fp=71808782448558fd&bpcl=39967673&biw=1366&bih=631

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that is one of the purposes of [`GM_setvalue()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue), it stores data, *per script*, and across domains.

Beware that the bog-standard `GM_setValue()` is somewhat problematic. It can use lots of global resources or cause a script instance to crash.

Here are some guidelines:

1. Do not use `GM_setValue()` to store anything but strings. For anything else, use a serializer such as [**GM_SuperValue**](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/107941). Even innocent looking integers can cause the default `GM_setValue()` to crash.
2. Rather than store lots of small variables, it may be better to wrap them in an object and store that with one of the serializers.

---

Finally note that [`localStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) has a specific meaning in javascript, and `localStorage` ***is*** domain specific.

Answer (score -1):

http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue

```
foo = "This is a string";

GM_setValue('myEntry', foo);
```

http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue

```
bar = GM_getValue('myEntry');

bar = GM_getValue('myOtherEntry', "default value if no value was found");
```

http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_deleteValue

```
GM_deleteValue('myEntry');

GM_deleteValue('myOtherEntry');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

```
foo = "this is a string";

localStorage.setItem('myEntry', foo);

bar = localStorage.getItem('pointer') || "default value";

localStorage.removeItem('myEntry');
```

or just...

```
localStorage.myEntry = "this is a string";

bar = localStorage.myEntry;
```

Comment: You did not address the question's cross-domain concerns.